# How to float right menu headers

Tags: css

my BOOTPLY... [MY BOOTPLY HERE](http://www.bootply.com/zHG4nPE2kV#)

I need my menu items (car, house, street, boat) to float right at same height level as my logo (for desktop dimensions) and everything else to stay the same as current (including mobile toggle menu behaviour).

Is that possible to achieve?

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

/***** Menu *****/
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    min-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-nav a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.navbar-nav a:link {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'century schoolbook';
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: overline;
    text-decoration-color: #A10000;
}

.brand-name a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.brand-name img {
    max-width: 137px;
    padding: 8px;
/*position:absolute;*/
    left: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar-form input,.form-inline input {
    width: auto;
}

#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

#sidebar.affix-top {
    position: static;
}

#sidebar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'LuzSans-Book';
    font-size: 14px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #A10000;
    color: #000;
 margin-top:4px;
 margin-bottom:4px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    background-color: #000;
 margin-top:4px;
 margin-bottom:4px;
}

.navbar-custom-social {
    height: 15px;
    float: right;
    clear: none;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
    padding-top: 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #777;
    padding: 0;
    height: inherit;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    width: 100%;
}

p.ajaxSearch_intro {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,.navbar-default .navbar-form {
    padding: 0;
}

/*toggle btn */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #A10000;
}

#nav.affix .logo_wrap {
    display: none;
}

#nav.affix-top .logo_wrap {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/assets/images/header-background.png);
    background-color: #fff;
}

#nav.affix .logo_wrap-text {
    display: none;
}

#nav.affix-top .logo_wrap-text {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/assets/images/header-background.png);
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header id="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
                       
                        <div class="clearfix container navbar-fixed-top">
                            <div class="clearfix menu-container">
                                <div class="pull-right clearfix toggle_btn_wrap">
                                    <a class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left brand-name">
                                    <a href="#"><img alt="***brandlogo***" src="assets/images/logo.png"></a>
                                </div>
                              <div class="clearfix prevent-float"></div>
                                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                   <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                                  <li>
                                    <a href="/car" title="car">car</a>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                    <a href="/house" title="house">house</a>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                    <a href="/street" title="street">street</a>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                    <a href="/boat" title="boat">boat</a>
                                     </li>
  </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div></div></div>

</div></header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `display:inline-block;` on both divs that contain your logo and menu items and then float the menu item div to the right.

Comment: just tried, couldnt get it to work. Menu items dont align same height level and mobile toggle menu floats right also. Can you please show me solution in my BOOTPLY? I am confused.

Comment: OK; I am one step closer, with inline-block it is better, however now my mobile toggle menu is also floated right instead of full width. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post a link to what you have

Comment: I updated my bootply... http://www.bootply.com/zHG4nPE2kV#    - Please click the mobile phone icon to see the toggle menu behaviour (which sadly floats right).

Comment: Use `@media` to `float:none;` on the menu

Comment: perfect, that did it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The essential necessary changes are:

1.) Make sure that the CSS rule for `.navbar-nav`, contains `float:right`

2.) From the DIV `<div class="clearfix prevent-float"></div>`, remove both classes.

Now the two elements can be next to each other. They are not yet, but that is due to various padding and/or margin settings, which you also have to adjust.

Comment: thank you. I implemented (1) and I removed that line code (however, now the mobile toggle menu also floats right). So it doesnt solve my problem. Please see updated BOOTPLY. Can you please make suggested changes in my BOOTPLY because I am confused as nothing seems to work.